# How do I determine if certain behavior is caused by a bug?

Tags: google-chrome

Let's say I found odd behavior in Google Chrome, but I'm not sure if this is the default behavior or not. How do I determine if it is a bug? Could I just file it as a bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)?

Comment: Report it.  Let people responsible for writing Chrome decide if it's a bug

Comment: I think, if application doesn't function as expected, then it has bugs...

Answer (score 2):

If I were unsure about certain behavior, I would do a few things.

1. If I were to be the developer of the program, would I want this to happen? If the answer is "Most definitely not", then its a bug. In all other cases, more research is required.
2. If I were to be the developer of the program, would I consider this "feature" to be as user-friendly as the rest of the program?
3. Google for what happens and see if other people experience it as well. If you find some discussion about people having the same issue and how to solve it, its most likely a bug. If you find discussions where people give answers to how to change the behavor, its likely to be a feature of the program. If no one talks about it, its probably a bug that is relatively new.
4. Ask other users for their opinion, which could be done through superuser. Just asking how to detect if its a bug is a way and then try and determine yourself, but if you just tell us what the possible bug is that you encountered, we can shed some light on it.
5. It never hurts to submit a bug report, even if something is not a bug. It is a sign to the developer that something is not clear and may need some changes, such as adding a tooltip or help section about why something is happening.